# Django access context data with a forloop.counter

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm trying to access context data via the forloop.counter.
I have two loops and my data should be accesed by `{{ data.[loop1xloop2].i_want_this}}` in the html.

Example context data:

```py
{'data': { '0x0' : { 'i_want_this' : 'value'}, '0x1' : {'i_want_this':...}, ...}}
```

I'm trying to display this data in a table which is generated by two forloops anyway.
I tried using djangos with tag to traverse the context structure but it seems that django doesn't recognize my created variable. I tried this:

```html
{% for day in days%}
    {% with daycounter=forloop.counter0|stringformat:"s" %}            
    {% with daykey=daycounter|add:"x0"|stringformat:"s" %} #tried it for the first loop by hardcoding loop1x0
            
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="6"  >{{day}}</td>
# value is the importend part
            <td ><input type="text" name="arbeit{{ forloop.counter0 }}0" value="{{data.daykey.i_want_this}}">{{data.0x0.i_want_this}} {{daykey}}</td>
                [...]
            {% for i in range %}
        <tr>
            <td class="border border-slate-950"><input class="w-full border-none" type="text" name="arbeit{{ forloop.parentloop.counter0 }}{{forloop.counter}}" id="arbeit{{ forloop.parentloop.counter0 }}{{forloop.counter}}"></td>
       </tr>
                   [...]
            {% endfor %}
            
        {% endwith %}
        {% endwith %}
        {% endfor %}
```

Directly addressing the value with `{{data.0x0.i_want_this}}` works and `{{daykey}}` also shows "0x0" but using {{data.daykey.i_want_this}} doesn't.

Is there something I'm not seeing or does django simply not have this functionalety?

Comment: Django deliberately did not include subscripting in the template language, because it often means that you try to implement business logic into the template, that belongs in the view.

Comment: It is the responsibility of the view to pass data to the template in an accessible form. This is not only often easier to bugfix, etc. but also more efficient, since Django's template language often is not that good with processing large amounts of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there something I'm not seeing or does django simply not have this functionalety?

Django *deliberately* did not include subscripting (i.e. `…[…]`) or calling methods (the methods are called with no parameters if it is a method (i.e. `.…(…)`), but you can not call methods with parameters in the Django templates).

This is for a good reason: often people doing this, do this when writing complicated expressions in the template. This is *not* what a template is supposed to do. A template should be given the data in an accessible format such that just enumerating over data, and rendering the data is sufficient.

If you would write (complicated) queries in the Django template, this often also would result in *N+1 problems* and finally Django's template engine is not extremely fast, so interpreting large chunks of data would produce content in a slow manner, and to make things even worse, the template does not support "*streaming*", so it is only passed to the client when the template is rendered completely.

If you really want to do this, there is an alternative template engine called [*Jinja* <sup>[jinja-doc]</sup>](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/) that supports these, but regardless, it is not a good idea to do this in the template. You should not fix the template, you should fix the view.

Comment: Thank you! this totally makes sense. The template logic should be simple.I changed my view and context like you suggested and it worked fine :)